# Optimizing UV space and maintaining texel density?

Tags: texturing, uv

Modeling this sword. Im having trouble figuring out how to use more UV space while maintaining texel density.

[image]

You can see here, the islands cant  be scaled up more without going outside the boundaries. Furthermore, I would like to get higher resolution out of the handle wrap for texturing in substance. (2 long skinny islands in UV map). But again, those cant be scaled up without breaking the edges.

[image]

Here is the handle wrap, textured in substance.

[image]

I've seen game ready models with much better resolution for things like this, seen here.

https://www.artstation.com/artwork/Jl6aO0

Comment: This question the way it is asked currently, is either too specific (won't help anyone else), or needs focus (*How to optimize UV unwrapping* is too general of a question...). The tape going around the handle is a repeatable texture and so it could be just a repeatable, seamless pattern, with A LOT of resolution: https://i.imgur.com/YayvQHm - if you have some dirt, you could still make it repeatable each 200° or so: https://i.imgur.com/kqaFxb0

Comment: You can rotate it 45 degrees to make it longer.  You can also, you know, break it up.  UV seams have minimal impact outside of certain texturing methods.  You have some places that are clearly occluded on your wrap, making these obvious seaming points anyways, even if seams were something to be worried about.  Better still, though, to retopo that wrap and handle into a single manifold mesh, but if you want, you can wait until after texturing the wrap and handle to do so-- and then you can use an 8k "high poly" image, and a completely different retopo UV with a 1k image.